# Spacing between sticky navbar and element when click to scroll

Tags: html, css

I have this feature for my website where I click a link from, ***example:*** `index.html` and in that page, it has a link `<a href="page.html#id">Link</a>`, and it takes me to another page and it scrolls down to that div holding the `#id`. But, it gets covered by my sticky navbar when it scrolls down. How can I make some space between that div and he sticky navbar?

How can I fix this issue? If we're talking about luck, I was able to find some demo and help regarding this concern, but it only shows how to do it on the same page, but what if I'm on another page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the top of the image inside of the div. I think that should do it.